# Unable to set correct column width in Vuetify

Tags: javascript, css, vuejs2, flexbox, vuetify.js

I am attempting to replicate this page layout with Vuetify

[image]

but what I am getting is this

[image]

Here is the code

```
    <Section>
      <div slot="contents">
        <v-form ref="form">
          <v-container>
            <v-layout row>
              <v-layout column class="mr-4">
                <v-flex xs6>
                  <v-text-field v-bind="fields.app" v-model="selectedTemplateApp" disabled />
                </v-flex>
                <v-flex xs6>
                  <v-text-field v-bind="fields.name" v-model="templateModel.name" />
                </v-flex>
                <v-flex xs6>
                  <v-text-field v-bind="fields.included" v-model="templateModel.included" />
                </v-flex>
              </v-layout>

              <v-layout column class="mr-2 ml-2">
                <v-flex xs6>
                  <v-select
                    :items="typeSelect"
                    v-bind="fields.type"
                    item-value="value"
                    item-text="text"
                    v-model="templateModel.type"
                    @input="toggleDynamic"
                  />
                  <v-text-field v-bind="fields.body" v-model="templateModel.body" />
                </v-flex>
                <v-flex xs6>
                  <v-select
                    :items="operationSelect"
                    v-bind="fields.algorithmOperation"
                    item-value="value"
                    item-text="text"
                    v-model="templateModel.algorithmOperation"
                  />
                </v-flex>
              </v-layout>
            </v-layout>

           <div v-if="showCustom">
            <v-divider></v-divider>
            <p>Customized appearance and message can be over-written via Send Alert</p>
            <v-layout row>
              <v-layout column class="pr-4">
                <v-flex xs6>
                  <v-layout row>
                    <v-checkbox class="shrink"></v-checkbox>
                    <v-text-field
                      v-bind="fields.alertTextColor"
                      v-model="templateModel.alertTextColor"
                      placeholder="#4A4A4A"
                    />
                    <ColorPickerButton
                      v-bind:field-name="'alertTextColor'"
                      v-bind:init-color="templateModel.alertTextColor"
                      v-on:update-color="getUpdatedColor"
                    ></ColorPickerButton>
                  </v-layout>
                </v-flex>

                <v-flex xs6>
                  <v-layout row>
                    <v-checkbox class="shrink"></v-checkbox>
                    <v-text-field
                      v-bind="fields.alertBackgroundColor"
                      v-model="templateModel.alertBackgroundColor"
                      placeholder="#4A4A4A"
                    />
                    <ColorPickerButton
                      v-bind:field-name="'alertBackgroundColor'"
                      v-bind:init-color="templateModel.alertBackgroundColor"
                      v-on:update-color="getUpdatedColor">
                    </ColorPickerButton>
                  </v-layout>
                </v-flex>
                <v-flex xs6>
                  <v-layout row>
                    <v-checkbox class="shrink"></v-checkbox>
                    <v-text-field
                      v-bind="fields.alertTextboxColor"
                      v-model="templateModel.alertTextboxColor"
                      placeholder="#FFFFFF"
                    />
                    <ColorPickerButton
                      v-bind:field-name="'alertTextboxColor'"
                      v-bind:init-color="templateModel.alertTextboxColor"
                      v-on:update-color="getUpdatedColor"
                    ></ColorPickerButton>
                  </v-layout>
                </v-flex>
                <v-flex xs6>
                  <v-layout row wrap>
                    <v-flex xs1>
                      <v-checkbox class="shrink"></v-checkbox>
                    </v-flex>
                    <v-text-field
                      v-bind="fields.backgroundImageUrl"
                      v-model="templateModel.backgroundImageUrl"
                      placeholder="Background Image URL - leave blank to use background color"
                      persistent-hint/>
                  </v-layout>
                </v-flex>
              </v-layout>

              <v-layout column>
                <v-flex xs6>
                  <v-text-field
                    v-bind="fields.headerText"
                    v-model="templateModel.headerText"
                    placeholder="An Alert has been issued"
                  />
                </v-flex>
                <v-flex xs6>
                  <v-textarea
                    v-bind="fields.bodyText"
                    v-model="templateModel.bodyText"
                    placeholder="Please verify your identity."
                    hint="HTML allowed"
                    persistent-hint
                    rows=3
                  />
                </v-flex>
                <v-flex xs6>
                  <v-layout row wrap>
                  <v-checkbox class="shrink"></v-checkbox>
                  <v-text-field
                    v-bind="fields.logoUrl"
                    v-model="templateModel.logoUrl"
                    placeholder="Custom Logo URL"
                    persistent-hint
                  />
                  </v-layout>
                </v-flex>
              </v-layout>
            </v-layout>
           </div>
          </v-container>
        </v-form>
      </div>
    </Section>
```

The issue is that the left column in the bottom row is wider than the left column in the top row, and they should both line up, but for some reason it doesn't. If I apply the `shrink` class to the individual items within the row, they shrink, but the overall row width stays the same, and if I apply `shrink` to the column, then it's way too narrow.

What do I need to change to get the columns in the bottom section to align with the columns in the top section?

Comment: I would suggest that you do a snippet (jsfiddle/jsbin... whatever) It's easier to help ;)

Comment: specifically if you can share the props in the js

Answer (score 0):

You are putting your bottom checkbok in an additional `flex` container this is what creates additional padding/margin, remove that and it should align. Alternatively you could remove the `flex` margin/padding with `mx-0 px-0`